# Calculate the entropy of a list of 2D points in Matlab

Tags: arrays, matlab, statistics, data-analysis, entropy

I have a list of points in an array like this

```
points = [[1,2];[2,5];[7,1]...[x,y]]
```

The x is between 0 and 1020 and y is between 0 and 1920.

How can I calculate the entropy of the points array in Matlab?

Many thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I assume you want to consider each `[x,y]` point as one data point. Let us define some exemplary data:

```
A = [[1,2];[2,5];[7,1];[1,2]];
```

First we give equal points equal identifiers, we can do this using

```
[~,~,ic] = unique(A, 'rows');
```

Then we compute the frequency and with that the probability of each identifier:

```
[frequency, ~] = histcounts(ic,max(ic));
probability = frequency/sum(frequency);
```

With this we can immediately compute the entropy:

```
entropy = -sum(probability .* log(probability))
```

(Make sure you use the right logarithm, different fields conventionally use different bases.)

Comment: Thank you so much.

Comment: Using a scalar second input for `histcounts` is very useful. I wasn't aware of that. Much neater than the akward-looking `histcounts(ic, [1:max(ic) inf])`. Also, you can directly use `probability = histcounts(ic, max(ic), 'Normalization', 'probability')`

Comment: Oh that is neat - but you have to admit it is less golfy!

Comment: Can I kindly ask how this would be updated for a 3D point array with x,y and z? Many thanks!

Comment: @Mohammad the code should work for points of an arbitrary number of dimensions, we are just comparing `'rows'` of the matrix `A` - it does not matter how long they are.