# Entropy function for 3D point array in Matlab?

Tags: arrays, matlab, statistics, data-analysis, entropy

For an array in this format

```
A = [[1,2,3]; [4,5,6]; ... [x, y, z]];
```

How can I calculate the entropy of the points array in Matlab?

Many thanks!

Comment: You should elaborate on how you define "entropy" here. What do you actually want to calculate, do you have any formula? Also, please provide a [mre], and tell us your specific problem in terms of programming.

Comment: How does this differ from your [previous question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/58289817/2586922) for the 2D case? Can't the same approach as in the accepted answer be used here?